# I want to scroll page on particular URL

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-pagescroller

On my one page there is a button "Get Started" and URL of button is URL:localadvertisingthatworks.com/test#my_site.
I want When I click on that button it redirect on my home page's particular section.Is there any code of jquery to scroll the page on particular url.

```html
<a href="http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/test#my_site">Link</a>

<a name="my_site>Anchor</a>
```

I have tried this code but it is not working in firefox and ie.So please give me some jquery code for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `id` on your `section` so it will be automatic, scroll when pageload.

```html
<a href="http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/test/#my_site">Link</a>

<a name="my_site>Anchor</a>
```

Comment: which id?same as my_site?

Comment: yes, you need to set `id` on `section` so he will go to that `section` after load.

Comment: but i see on you `section` dont have `id`.

Comment: Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so say that on your front page, you have a section. That section needs to have some kind of id, for example `#my_section_id` (the html will be like: `<section id="my_section_id">...</section>`). Then your button must point to it:

```
<a href="#my_section_id" class="scroll">My scrollable section</a>
```

Now the `.scroll` class is here to distinguish from regular links. Because you if you're on the same page as the section, and you also want to scroll to that section, you don't want page reload. The smooth scroll jquery script that will do this looks like this:

```
$(".scroll").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = ( $(this).attr('href') !== undefined ) ? $(this).attr('href') : $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var hash = href.split('#');
    var url_hash = '#' + hash[1];
    if ($(url_hash).length > 0) {
        var offset = ( $(window).width()<769) ? 20 : 100;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(url_hash).offset().top-offset
        }, 1000);
    }
    else{
        location.href = href;
    }
});

if(window.location.hash){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var $scrollto = $(hash);
    if($scrollto.length){
        var offset = ( $(window).width()<769) ? 20 : 100;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $scrollto.offset().top-offset
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

The offset is something that you need to adjust for yourself

```
var offset = ( $(window).width()<769) ? 20 : 100;
```

Depending on how far you want to scroll to your section.

The first part will take care that you scroll to that section if you're on the same page, and we have `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default link behavior. The second part looks if you're on a different page, and will load the page the scroll is on, and scroll to it once you're on it.

The only thing you need to add is the `.scroll` class to your link. This can be a bit tricky if you want to add it in the menu, but it's possible to do with menu walker modifications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to reduce length from var offset = ( $(window).width()<769) ? 20 : 100;

Comment: The `offset` variable is either 20, or 100, depending if your window width is less than 769 or not. So just manually change those. On your desktop you need to manually change 100 to the value that suits you. Put 50 and see if the scroll goes above or below the section

Comment: Did you put `scroll` class on your link. Can you post the link to your page?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location.hash){
    var e = window.location.hash;
   setTimeout(() => {
    if($(e).position() != undefined){
      var top_position = $(e).position().top-120 ;
      $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: top_position }, "slow");
      $(e).css("background-color", "#E3E3E3").animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }, 2200);
    }
   }, 2000);
  }
```

// for animate function you need jquery ui cdn
// jQuery UI - v1.10.4 - 2014-01-17